# In onMenuClose or onBlur event of react-select identify whether event is triggered by option selection or the blur

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

In react select onBlur event or onMenuClose event is triggered when user selects the option or blur (click outside of the control).

So I want to perform the business logic on blur event if user has not selected an option.

In other words I want to know how blur event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

onBlur event is triggered when the focusable HTML Element loses focus. Maybe it's easiest to see if select option was changed? Don't know how your implementation looks though but maybe this will help you.